# Grouping methods without losing the use of the this keyword

Tags: javascript, methods, this, grouping

In the following code how do I get the `this` keyword to bind to `Square`?

```
Square.prototype.is = {
  king: function () { this.piece === "K" }
  queen: function () { this.piece === "Q" }
  ...
};
```

I know I can later on use `call`/`apply` but the whole point was to get from

```
this.isKing()
```

to

```
this.is.king()
```

making it more readable (also grouping the methods together)

```
this.is.king.apply(this)
```

seems like a step backwards.

Comment: What does `this` refer to? `this` refering to a Chess instance or `this` referring to some other object?

Comment: I edited my post, the class in questions is named `Square` not `Chess`. All the `this` keywords refer to a `Square` instance

Comment: What if you return`this` on both king and queen fns

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get what you mean.


You mean the methods in the first code block?

The problem is going from

    Square.prototype.isKing = function() { return this.piece === "K"}

to

    Square.prototype.is = {
      king: function() { return this.piece === "K" }
    }

changes what the `this` key refers to.

In the first example it refers to a Square instance, in the second it refers to the Square.prototype.is object.

I might have answered your first question wrong, sorry for the confussion

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).  This is a syntax that is supported by all major browsers now.  Using arrow functions allows us to leverage the outer scope's `this`.

An example using `Class`:

```js
class Square {
  constructor(){
    this.piece = null;
    this.is = {
      king: () => this.piece === "K",
      queen: () => this.piece === "Q"
    }
  }
};

const square = new Square();
square.piece = 'K';

console.log(square.is.king());
console.log(square.is.queen());
```

If you're determined to use ES5 syntax:

```js
var Square = function Square() {
  var _this = this;
  this.piece = null;
  this.is = {
    king: function() { return _this.piece === "K" },
    queen: function() { return _this.piece === "Q" }
  };
};


var square = new Square();
square.piece = 'K';

console.log(square.is.king());
console.log(square.is.queen());
```

Finally, per @Bergi's comment, here's one more approach, using arrow functions and objects, without any `Class`es.

```js
const Square = function Square() {  
  this.piece = null;
  this.is = {
    king: () => this.piece === "K",
    queen: () => this.piece === "Q"
  };
};


const square = new Square();
square.piece = 'K';

console.log(square.is.king());
console.log(square.is.queen());
```

Comment: I have a lot of methods. My `class Square` block would have a few hundred lines of code. Do you still recommend doing this?

Is combining the .prototype way of defining methods and the class way an option?

Comment: Of the two approaches, it seems like the ES6 class-based approach is the less verbose, although they are very similar in length.

Comment: This doesn't need `class`es at all, the main feature of your approach are arrow functions that are created in the scope of the constructor.

Comment: @Bergi true enough.  I've added one more simplified approach.  Also cleaned up the ES5 example...

Comment: I just wanted you to edit the first sentence from "*I would suggest using ES6 classes.*" to "*I would suggest using ES6 arrow functions.*" :-)

Comment: Done, with some additional edits.  Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this does not answer directly to your question, but the `is` functions that are commonly found in third party libraries usually have the following signature: `is(type)`.

In this fashion, you could write:

```
square.prototype.is = function(type) {
  switch (String(type).toLowerCase()) {
    case "king": return this.piece === "K";
    case "queen": return this.piece === "Q";
    default: return false;
  }
}
```

Assuming type would be a `String`. But it can an `Number` defined in an `Object` to act as a `Enum`.

I hope you won't consider this off-topic as it can be a solution to consider alternative ways :)

Comment: +1,                                                        this is a much better solution than what was asked for :-)